# Java2D: if statement doesn`t work with java.awt.Color

Tags: java, java-2d

I have a `getPixelColour` function:

```
Color getPixelColor(int x, int y) {
    if(mazeImage == null) System.out.println(":(");
    int pixel = mazeImage.getRGB(x, y);
    int  red = (pixel & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
    int  green = (pixel & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
    int  blue = pixel & 0x000000ff;
    return new Color(red,green,blue);
}
```

For example a pixel is black, and `System.out.println(getPixelColor(x,y) + " " + Color.BLACK);` 
writes `java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0] java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]`

But `getPixelColor(x,y) == Color.BLACK` returns `false`. What's wrong with it?

Comment: If you found any of the below answers helpful you should accept one. As you post more questions members will be reluctant to help you unless you accept useful answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing two different `Color` objects which will return false (i.e., two different objects at different memory locations).

If you wish to properly compare them, use `equals()`:

```
getPixelColor(x, y).equals(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `getPixelColor(x, y) == Color.BLACK` 
try 
`Color.BLACK.equals(getPixelColor(x, y))`

You should also read up on the `equals` method in Java and when it is appropriate to use it vs. the `==` operator.

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
getPixelColor(x,y).equals(Color.BLACK);
```

I'm sure you will get the result you expect.

The `==` operator in java is reference equality, and since `getPixelColor()` returns a new instance of `Color` it'll never `==` to `Color.BLACK` as this a static reference to another instance that happens to be the colour black.

Answer (score 2):

`Color` is an object and `==` compares not the contents of the objects but the instances. So there can be several `Color` objects containing the RGB values (0,0,0).

You want to compare with `col1.equals(col2)`.

You might look around this site and find plenty of other questions regaring `==` and `equals`. As an example:

[Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)